# Sitecore DEF 2.0.1 Custom Filter Expressions

Tags: xconnect, data-exchange-framework

How can I specify multiple 'Contact Filter' or create a custom one for 'Read Contacts from xConnect' pipeline step ?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Could you provide some example of multiple 'Contact Filter'? It would help to find some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the Filter Expression template has these insert options:

[image: filter expression insert options]

This means that Filter Expressions can have sub Filter Expressions.

Then it's just a matter of setting the desired Logical Operator on each Filter Expression.

[image: filter expression logical operator]

I was able to run this without any errors and I got the result I was expecting. If you get errors, it's probably because something was misconfigured. If you don't any get errors, but don't get the results you expect, test a very simple case and also make sure to clear out the `Requested At` and `Last Run Finished` fields on the pipeline batch to get a fresh start.

[image: reset pipeline batch timestamps]

I'm also a fan of clearing out all of the contacts prior to doing this type of testing. Run these queries on both shards ([source](https://andypaz.com/2019/11/27/delete-xdb-contacts/)):

```
delete
FROM [CLIENT_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[ContactIdentifiers]
 
delete
FROM [CLIENT_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[ContactIdentifiersIndex]
 
delete
FROM [CLIENT_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[ContactFacets]
   
delete
FROM [CLIENT_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[InteractionFacets]
 
delete
FROM [CLIENT_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]
 
delete
FROM [CLIENT_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[Contacts]
```